# Resizing images keeping the same pixel ratio

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

Using Ubuntu 10.10.

I want to resize images keeping the same pixel ratio. Currently I have images with 300*300. I want to crop the images but want the ratio 300*300 to be maintained.

Which tool/plugin/software can I use for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done from terminal.  [How to Quickly Resize, Convert & Modify Images from the Linux Terminal](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/):

> ImageMagick will try to preserve the aspect ratio if you use this
> command. It will alter the image to fit within a 200×100 area, but the
> image may not be exactly 200×100. If you want to force the image to
> become a specific size – even if it messes up the aspect ratio – add
> an exclamation point to the dimensions:
>
> ```
> convert example.png -resize 200×100! example.png
> ```

You can also use GIMP.

> GIMP is expandable and extensible. It is designed to be augmented with
> plug-ins and extensions to do just about anything. The advanced
> scripting interface allows everything from the simplest task to the
> most complex image manipulation procedures to be easily scripted.

<sup>Source: http://docs.gimp.org/en/introduction.html</sup>

To install GIMP, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: convert: invalid argument for option `-resize': 200×200! @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2343. I got this error while running the above command. Any idea

Comment: Did you replace the example.png with the name of you image in both locations? :)

Comment: yes i did it.. convert product_1_green_1.png -resize 490×490! product_1_green_1.png

Comment: So it did work?

Comment: nop.. sorry for the confusion.. It did't worked, what i meant to say was i changed the image file names.