# Resizing with imagemagick error message

Tags: resize, imagemagick

I am experiencing one particular problem using imagemagick:

Everytime I try to resize a certain .png or .jpg by typing the simplest command

```
convert bbb.png -resize 200×200! bbb.png
```

I get this:

```
convert.im6: invalid argument for option `-resize': 200×200 @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2382.
```

I am working in the right path, so that shouldn't be the problem.
The only info on this matter I found is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149297/resizing-images-with-same-pixel-ratio).

Since there isn't any further explaination there, I'd be very thankful if you help me further.

Comment: It looks like you copy-pasted the command (or at least the `200×200` part): the `×` is a non-ASCII character, making it an 'invalid argument'. Try again but actually type out the `200x200`.

Comment: @steeldriver I think you're right. Are you writing an answer?

Comment: of course, I didn't think about the simplest thing ....  (I am pretty new in using Linux, so that's the reason. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 12):

Your command is wrong:

```
convert bbb.png -resize 200×200! bbb.png
```

the `×` is a non-ASCII character.

Use this:

```
convert bbb.png -resize 200x200! bbb.png
```

Comment: +1 very decent to do it like this, and a correct answer :)

Comment: yes, it worked properly after doing that. Thank you!

Comment: @user414935 As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Same problem, I copied the resolution from the Get Info dialog on macOS